# Creating a console in Kivy

Tags: python, console, kivy

I'm trying to write a very basic Kivy program that will use 3 different layouts to split the screen into :

- a header  (at the top of the screen)
- a text zone (in the middle of the screen)
- a console (at the bottom of the screen)

So far I was thinking to use a main gridLayout, in which I use 3 different floatLayout.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
class Logo(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(rows=3)
        layoutTop = FloatLayout(size=(100,300))
        layoutMid = FloatLayout(size=(100,300))
        layoutDown = FloatLayout(size=(100,300))

        logo = Image(source='imagine.png',size_hint=(.25,.25),pos=(30,380))
        blank = Label(text='', font_size = '25sp',pos=(-200,100))
        titre = Label(text='#LeCubeMedia',font_size='40sp',pos=(0,280))
        ip = Label(text='192.168.42.1',font_size='25sp',pos=(250,280))

        layoutTop.add_widget(titre)
        layoutTop.add_widget(logo)
        layoutTop.add_widget(ip)
        layoutMid.add_widget(blank)

        layout.add_widget(layoutTop)
        layout.add_widget(layoutMid)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Logo().run()
```

Actually my problem is regarding the creation of the console. I have read a lot of the [Kivy docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.html), but I am still looking for a good way to do this type of widget.

How do you think it would be if I send something with a Python `print` into my Kivy app, and then refresh as soon as I need to send something else (to erase the previous print). This way it would be a console-like. But, so far I have not much ideas..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen 2 types of consoles in Kivy. The first is a multiline textinput in a scrollview where you append the new text to the old in the textinput. The second is a BoxLayout or GridLayout in a Scrollview where each console output is a separate label in the layout.

Comment: Do you have any snippet code as example ? I can barely realize how to code this type of widget.

Comment: This is an attempt at making a Python REPL. It doesn't work yet, but the console-like parts do. https://github.com/brousch/krepla/tree/master/krepla

Comment: Hey the console provided in this krepla github works well to me. I just have one question, how can I make the "Enter" key works instead of clicking on Enter everytime ? Is that even possible ? Thank you

Comment: That would require overriding the defaults of the text input. An entirely new question.

Comment: Ok then I start a new one. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/akshayaurora/kivy/blob/kivy_console/kivy/uix/kivyconsole.py) was a attempt trying stuff out with kivy, the code is old and you might need to adjust it a bit to make it run with latest kivy. Kivy-designer also includes this. This is using the simple way of using two textinputs, 1 for history and the other for input.

A better way to do a proper console would be to use [pyte](https://github.com/selectel/pyte) and draw characters directly onto the canvas of a widget. This way one would get VT emulation for free.

Comment: Thanks for both git repo. Just, what's VT emulation ?